# React renders 3 times instead of 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't understand why React render 3 times in this example:

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const addTimer = () => {
    console.log('timer', timer);
    setTimer(timer + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Use effect');
  
    setInterval(addTimer, 8000);
  }, [])


  return <h5>Time: {console.log('Render') || timer}</h5>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Output of console:

```html
Render
Use effect
timer 0
Render
timer 0
Render
timer 0 (infinity)
```

The first render is initial and we see in console `Render`. Then after initialization `useEffect` starts and we see `Use effect` in console and we initialize timer every 8 seconds. I clearly understand that in `addTimer` function `timer` variable always will be 0. After 8 seconds we update state from 0 to 1, so we can see `timer 0` and after `Render` because now we have new state. If I'm right then in new state `timer` is 1 but when `addTimer` starts second time we again update state to 1 but previous state already is 1, so we didn't update anything but we can see `Render` third time after `timer 0`. After this we will see only `timer 0` infinity times because we don't update state we always put 1 as a new state so there is no need in render again

Please explain me why in console I see third `Render`?

**P.S. I know how to properly update state and I understand that in `addTimer` function `timer` variable always will be 0. Please don't explain me this parts**

**P.S.S. It doesn't matter on React version here is examples**

Version `16.8.0`

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const addTimer = () => {
    console.log('timer', timer);
    setTimer(timer + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Use effect');
  
    setInterval(addTimer, 8000);
  }, [])


  return <h5>Time: {console.log('Render') || timer}</h5>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Version `17.0.0`

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  const addTimer = () => {
    console.log('timer', timer);
    setTimer(timer + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Use effect');
  
    setInterval(addTimer, 8000);
  }, [])


  return <h5>Time: {console.log('Render') || timer}</h5>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @EstusFlask I clearly understand why in my example `timer` in `addTimer` function is always 0. I can't understand why React render 3 times instead of 2?

Comment: I guess the example is misleading then, could be `setTimer(1)`. I see what you mean. Likely some kind of reconciliation happens, but I'm unaware of that. Interesting thing but shouldn't be a real issue because nothing should rely on render calls count,

Comment: @yousoumar It doesn't matter. I tried on versions `16.8.0`, `17.0.0` and `18.1.0`. You can copy and run my example and experiment with other versions. And I don't see that `useEffect` run several times, because I see only one message `Use effect` in console

Comment: I see @EzioMercer. Deleted the suggestion.

Comment: Yes both of you are right. It is not the real issue. I just want to understand why we have external rendering when state doesn't change second time?

Comment: Answered by the man himself here: [React component sometimes renders twice with unchanged state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883745/react-component-sometimes-renders-twice-with-unchanged-state)

Comment: @Ed_ Thank you! This isn't an answer as to why this is happening, but it means it's not my fault and React can re-render even though the state doesn't change :)